# Java regex expression to include underscore

Tags: java, regex

I am trying with the below line, which ignores underscore but I want to change it to include underscore.

```
String name = "$SF_Update$";
String regexp = "\\$(.*?)(?:[\\_].*)?\\$"; // want to change this line
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regexp);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(name);
```

I tried the below options:

```
String regexp ="\\$([a-zA-Z]+(?:_[a-zA-Z]+)*)\\$"
```

It includes underscore but it is considering the next line strings which doesn't have a $ at the end as well, like:
"$SF_Update$"
"$SF_Updateone"
Please provide a solution.

Comment: I think it would be enough to remove the `_` from the non-capturing group like this: `\\$(.*?)(?:[\\].*)?\\$`

Comment: Are you just wanting to capture everything between two dollar signs like `\\$([^$]+)\\$`?

Comment: I want to capture everything in between the $ but only the first underscore. "$SF_Update$"; and should not capture  "$SF_Update_one$";

Comment: Try `"\\$([^_$]+)_([^_$]+)\\$"`, `[^_$]+` matches one or more chars other than `_` and `$`. If there cannot be any whitespace inside, add `\\s` into the `[...]` (i.e. `"\\$([^_\\s$]+)_([^_\\s$]+)\\$"`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code:

```
String str1 = "$SF_Update$";
String str2 = "$SF_Update_One$";
String str3 = "$SF_Update_One";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\$([^_]+_{1}[^_]+)\\$");
Matcher matcher1 = pattern.matcher(str1);
Matcher matcher2 = pattern.matcher(str2);
Matcher matcher3 = pattern.matcher(str3);
if (matcher1.matches())
    System.out.println(str1 + " => " + matcher1.group(1));
else
    System.out.println(str1 + " => " + "No Match.");
if (matcher2.matches())
    System.out.println(str2 + " => " + matcher2.group(1));
else
    System.out.println(str2 + " => " + "No Match.");
if (matcher3.matches())
    System.out.println(str3 + " => " + matcher3.group(1));
else
    System.out.println(str3 + " => " + "No Match.");
```

Output:

```
$SF_Update$ => SF_Update
$SF_Update_One$ => No Match.
$SF_Update_One => No Match.
```

Comment: @user8059207, this doesn't help?

Comment: Sorry, I had some network issues, was not able to login.  No the result is only SF is getting selected as group(1), for group(0) the entire string is getting selected "$SF_Update$

Comment: @user8059207 what is the expected output? Please specify one or two input/output combinations.

Comment: input string = "$SF_Update$", and "$SF_Update_One$, the desired output which should appear in matcher.group(1) should be "SF_Update" only not SF_Update_One (only the first underscore should match).

Comment: hey Chiranjib, this is partially correct. The second string $SF_Update_One$ should not match because it has a second underscore.

Comment: Edited answer again, but this somehow feels wrong. Do rethink the use-case and simplify the logic.

Comment: Thanks Chiranjib, it worked, can you explain what does {1} means?

Comment: {1} matches the character before it exactly once. Read this, should help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/anchors-in-regular-expressions
If it's done, please mark as accepted answer

Comment: Hi Chiranjib, I have further question in this regex, and would like to ask in chat,can you come in chat?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this expresion:

```
\$[A-Za-z]+(_[A-Za-z]+)*\$
```

I do it in [Regex Online](https://regex101.com/)

And if the name could have numbers:

```
\$[A-Za-z0-9]+(_[A-Za-z0-9]+)*\$
```

And it rules for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to capture everything between $ and assert that underscore is present use this regex:

```
\\$(.*?)_([^_]*)\\$
```

`(.*?)` matches one symbol and next it tries to match underscore. If it doesn't, `(.*?)` matches this symbol and regex tries to match underscore again.

After underscore is matched, `([^_]*)` matches everything that is not underscore for 0 or more times.

Comment: This is capturing all the underscore in that string, how can it be used to capture only the first underscore and not the consecutive ones like:"$SF_Update$"; and should not capture "$SF_Update_one$";

Comment: This regex doesn't match `$SF_Update_one$`

Comment: sorry if I have confused you,may be I will ask the question this way: the matcher.group(1) should match (or select) only "$SF_Upadate$ and not $SF_Update_One$

Comment: Use `matcher.group(0)` to get all string matched by regex

Comment: Use `matcher.matches` to check if this regex matches string ` $SF_Update_One$`

Comment: @ Jay  matcher.group(0) give the output: $SF_Update$ and matcher.group(1) gives : SF alone.